# Next Js & Sanity - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I have been using sanity for a while and i have checked the query it works great on React app when used with useState and useEffect.

I recently migrated to Nextjs 13, with getStaticProps the query works but only in the pages section.

I have checked the sanity groq query, that is working.

As i want to use some components, Whenever i try to run the same...i get "**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".**

folder structure

frontend

- component / about / about.jsx

- pages

- index.jsx --- here i want to import the component.

The Code.. AboutCheck

```
import groq from "groq";
import createClient from "../client";

const AboutCheck = ({ HeroSection }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {HeroSection.map((item) => (
        <li>{item.heroheading}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const query = `*[_type == "HeroSection"]{
  heroheading,
  herosubheading,
  ctaButtonText,
coverImage {
    asset -> {
      url
    }
  }
}`;
  const HeroSection = await createClient.fetch(query);
  return {
    props: {
      HeroSection,
    },
  };
}

export default AboutCheck;
```

Index

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
import AboutCheck from '@/component/AboutCheck'

errorconst inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

function Home() {

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
          <p>
            Hey 
          </p>
    <AboutCheck   />
       </>

  
  )
}
export default  Home;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5HGD.png)

I recently migrated to Nextjs 13, with getStaticProps the query works but only in the pages section.

I have checked the sanity groq query, that is working.

As i want to use some components, Whenever i try to run the same...i get "**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".**

Comment: which version of nextjs are you using ? 13.1 or 13.2 ?

Comment: it's a fresh installation v13.2.4

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use Nextjs data fetching methods in a regular component, it should be used in a page component that lives under the `pages` folder.

so what you have to do here, is to get rid of `getStaticProps` in `AboutCheck` and make it happen in `Home` to be able to fetch data there then pass it to `AboutCheck`

```js
function Home({ HeroSection }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <p>Hey</p>
      <AboutCheck HeroSection={HeroSection} />
    </>
  );
}
export default Home;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const query = `*[_type == "HeroSection"]{
    heroheading,
    herosubheading,
    ctaButtonText,
  coverImage {
      asset -> {
        url
      }
    }
  }`;
  const HeroSection = await createClient.fetch(query);
  return {
    props: {
      HeroSection,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Well, that was working i thought it would be just clean to use it with the components... Don't you think it defeats the purpose of the components.....

Comment: no, it's not against the purpose of components and technically speaking since `AboutCheck` is included in `Home`  so `getStaticProps` will run anyway when Home is called, so it's better to have the data available outside o`AboutCheck ` maybe you need the same data for another component so you don't need to fetch it twice also the data fetching methods are for pregenerating data for pages not for components

Comment: also think about the `Home` page rerendering multiple time, even if it is possible, it won't be a good approch to fetch data inside `AboutCheck` each time this happens