Sanity Error: Cannot Read Properties of Null(image)
I am generating a eccomerce project, but I have the following problem when generating the [image], it shows me an Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'image1')
Hero.tsx
import Image from "next/image";
import { client, urlFor } from "../lib/sanity";
 
async function getData(){
    const query = "*[_type == 'heroImage'][0]";
    
    const data = await client.fetch(query)
    
    return data;
}


export default async function Hero() {
    const data = await getData();
    console.log(data)
    return(
            <section className="mx-auto max-w-2xl px-4 sm:pb-6 lg:max-w-7xl lg:px-8">
                <div className="mb-8 flex flex-wrap justify-between md:mb-16">
                    <div className="mb-6 flex w-full flex-col justify-center sm:mb-12 lg:mb-0 lg:w-1/3 lg:pb-24 lg:pt-48">
                        <h1 className="mb-3 text-3xl font-bold text-black sm:text-5xl md:mb-5 md:text-5xl">Top Fashion for the best price!</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-12 flex w-full md:mb-16 lg:w-2/3">
                        <div className="relative left-12 top-12 z-10 -ml-12 overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-gray-100 shadow-lg md:left-16 md:top-16 lg:ml-0">
                        {data && data.image1 ? 
                        ( 
                            <Image 
                                src={urlFor(data.image1).url()}
                                alt="Great Photo"
                                className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
                                width={500}
                                height={500}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <p>Image not available</p>
                        )}
                        </div>    

                        <div className="overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-gray-100 shadow-lg">
                        {data && data.image1 ? 
                        ( 
                            <Image 
                                src={urlFor(data.image2).url()}
                                alt="Great Photo"
                                className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
                                width={500}
                                height={500}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <p>Image not available</p>
                        )} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>


            </section>
    )
};



sanity.ts
import {createClient} from 'next-sanity'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'

export const client = createClient({
    projectId: '9a6nfovq',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2022-03-07',
    useCdn: true,
})

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client)

export function urlFor(source: any) {
    return builder.image(source)
} 


I tried checking by putting query in sanity and its showing the data, but its not showing the images in my frontend of the application.
Please help, thank you all very much in advance!!!

Looks like it is already answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806148/next-js-sanity-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map
